# System.Byte[] displaying in Datagrid column

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datagrid

All columns are displaying correctly in the DataGrid except for one. I ran this sql query in MySqlWorkbench and it works so there is nothing wrong with that:

```
  string query = @"SELECT c.*,cc.CountryName ,(Select UserName FROM users WHERE User_ID = c.CreatedByUser) AS CreatedBy,
                      (select GROUP_CONCAT(AreaDescription) from pxpcountycodes where countyid=c.id) as AreaDescription, 
                      (select GROUP_CONCAT(cmr.AccountCode)) as Member  " +
                    " FROM counties c " +
                    " LEFT JOIN Countries cc ON c.CountryID = cc.ID " +
                    " LEFT JOIN PXPCountyCodes PXPc on c.ID = PXPc.CountyID" +
                    " LEFT JOIN customer cmr ON PXPc.MemberID = cmr.ID  " +
                    " WHERE c.Company_ID = ?companyID ";
```

And the code for the DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tblResults" OnItemDataBound="dgList_ItemCreated" AllowSorting="true" OnSortCommand="dgList_Sort" ID="dgList" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CountyName" HeaderText="County Name/PostCode" SortExpression="c.CountyName" ></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="c.Description"></asp:BoundColumn>   
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Member" HeaderText="Member" SortExpression="Member"/> 
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CountryName" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="cc.CountryName"></asp:BoundColumn>                   
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CountyPostCode" HeaderText="County/PostCode" SortExpression="c.CountyPostCode"></asp:BoundColumn>   
                    </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid>
```

The problem is with the `Member` column. This column displays a list of companies, so for example the column should display `CONWAY,NGWCLARE`. Some columns are trying to display around 5 companies so is the length causing a problem?

Code behind Grid:

```
DataSet ds = Lookups.County.GetAllCounties(Company.Current.CompanyID, ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Value, txtSearchBy.Text, IsActive, rbl_both.Checked, OrderBy, false, -1, "", 0);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dgList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dgList.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code behind code? How you are binding the DataGrid?

Comment: @RahulSingh I added the code to my question. Yes I am binding the DataGrid. All the columns except the `Member` are all displaying

Comment: Is there really the need of SELECT before GROUP_CONCAT(cmr.AccountCode)?

Comment: @sachin removing the SELECT didn't solve the problem

Comment: @user123456789 Did you inspect the content of ds.Tables[0] in debug mode?

Comment: @sachin Member is showing as System.Byte[] in ds.Tables[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. CASTing GROUP_CONCAT's output AS CHAR should fix the issue.

```
 string query = @"SELECT c.*,cc.CountryName ,(Select UserName FROM users WHERE User_ID = c.CreatedByUser) AS CreatedBy,
                      (select GROUP_CONCAT(AreaDescription) from pxpcountycodes where countyid=c.id) as AreaDescription, 
                      CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(cmr.AccountCode) As CHAR) as Member  " +
                    " FROM counties c " +
                    " LEFT JOIN Countries cc ON c.CountryID = cc.ID " +
                    " LEFT JOIN PXPCountyCodes PXPc on c.ID = PXPc.CountyID" +
                    " LEFT JOIN customer cmr ON PXPc.MemberID = cmr.ID  " +
                    " WHERE c.Company_ID = ?companyID ";
```